# How can I get the shared key from Log Analytics workspace in a Python runbook?

Tags: python, azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-runbook

I'm trying to get the primary/shared key from a Log Analytics Workspace in a Python Runbook to use with the Log Collector API for Auth. I've searched everywhere yet can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **RESTAPI** calls to get the Shared Keys for Log Analytics Workspace in Azure Automation Runbook.

Get [Shared Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspace-shared-keys/get-shared-keys?tabs=HTTP) from Log Analytics Workspace

Use below **RESTAPI** call to fetch the ***Shared Key*** for **Log Analytics Workspace** in a ***Azure Automation Runbook***. (Before calling API call you have to authenticate with your resources using AAD Oauth2)

```cs
# use POST method to get the Shared Key
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/{workspaceName}/sharedKeys?api-version=2020-08-01
```

[MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/api/overview) to access the logs from log analytics workspace

Steps to use [API calls in python](https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2016/01/05/azure-resource-manager-authentication-with-python/) from MSFT stack.

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was expecting the keys can be found in the portal....
Cheers!!